# show value on lattice dotplot

Tags: r, lattice

I have a dot plot:

[image]

Done using lattice `dotplot()` of my `resamples()` list. How do I display the values of each plot?

(my code is just `dotplot(resamples(list()))`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What package does `resamples` come from?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult without an example, but try this:

```
p <- dotplot(resamples(list()))
p
trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
panel.text(x=p$panel.args[[1]]$x,y=p$panel.args[[1]]$y,labels = *point_values*, pos=3, cex=0.5, col="red")
trellis.unfocus()
```